# Docusign returning RECIPIENTS_NOT_PROVIDED

Tags: xml, docusignapi

We are converting the JSON input to Docusign XML and trying to upload a document and then sending it to Docusign. But getting this error Call to URL, status :400: Error description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errorDetails xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <errorCode>RECIPIENTS_NOT_PROVIDED</errorCode> 
 <message>No recipients were found in the request.</message> 
</errorDetails>
```

But we do have mentioned the recipients in the xml as

```
<recipients>
 <signers>
  <signer>
    <recipientId>abc@gmail.com</recipientId>
    <email>abc@gmail.com</email>
    <name>abc@gmail.com</name>
  </signer>
 </signers>
</recipients>
```

Comment: It would be easier to determine if you gave us the XML. Please don't forget to remove the sensitive info from the header (if provided).

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you converting to XML if you have JSON? Docusign does support JSON so you might be able to save some time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a numerical value for `recipientId`, also your `name` should not be an email address once you move into a Production workflow.

Below is linked to the source that will provide the requirements for the call. The sample is in JSON, but it is the same for XML.

---

### Send an Envelope or Create a Draft Envelope

Sample Code from the help guide:

```
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
    {
        "email": "String content",
        "name": "String content",
        "recipientId": "1"
    }]
}
```

Converted to XML

```
<recipients>
 <signers>
  <signer>
    <email>String content</email>
    <name>String content</name>
    <recipientId>1</recipientId>
  </signer>
 </signers>
</recipients>
```

[DocuSign REST v2 API Guide - Send an Envelope or Create a Draft Envelope](https://08d1d92f490618f41c65-8fb00e97ac499a7066a18ce9c66b019b.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf#page=98)